# Pattern formation using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print a pattern of numbers in inverted triangle using Java.
I have tried many times by using different conditions but couldn't get exactly the same type of pattern. Sometimes the order of number gets changed or sometimes the number of spaces before the numbers gets changed. This is the basic structure of my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class S
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        int no = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        for (int x = no; x >= 1; x--)
        {
            for (int y = no; y >= 1; y--)
            {
                if ()
                    System.out.print(y) ;
                else ()
                    System.out.print (" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is:

```
5 4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2
    5 4 3
      5 4
        5
```

I can't get the proper condition that should come in **if** and **else**. I tried many but can't get the following pattern as it is.

How can we print pattern like this in Java

Can someone suggest what should come under the if and else coditions to get this pattern.

Comment: `x >= y`? Sure you've tried it all. :D

Comment: x >= y gives the pattern in which numbers in each row start from the row number i.e top row from 5, next row from 4 and so on. While I want each row to start from 5. When i put any other condition after the inner for loop to get the x back from 5, it changes the whole pattern and i get different shape of the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this::: just add a special integer i:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class S
{
public static void main (String args [])
{
    int no = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = no; x >= 1; x--)
    {
        for (int y = no; y >= 1; y--)
        {
            if (x > y){
                System.out.print((y+i)+" ") ;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print ("  ");
        }}
        System.out.println();
    i++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need any special conditions, you can answer your question just by using your loops.

```
for(int i=0; i< no; i++){
    for(int j=no; j>i; j--){
        System.out.print(j+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This should give you the correct output, all you need to do now is your formatting.

Comment: No this does't print exactly the same patern.